# Alternatives to archive.org

Tags: web-apps

I am attempting to view the history of a given website's landing page, however, the archive.org copy is missing all images from several of the copies. I am seeking an alternative tool that will allow me to browse such pages. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options available, but none of them are nearly as big and complete as [Archive.org](https://archive.org/web/) :

- **Archive.today**: https://archive.is/
- **Mementoweb**: http://timetravel.mementoweb.org/
- **Screenshots.com (defunct, redirects to domaintools.com)**: http://screenshots.com/
- **Arquivo.pt** : https://arquivo.pt/?l=en

Alternatively, there are [several Web Archiving Initiatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_archiving_initiatives) by several Non-Profits and Government Organizations. You have a chance of finding what you want if you contact these organizations but it might be extremely slow and ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

You should try http://timetravel.mementoweb.org/ which gathers many archive websites into one search query. ;)